# CSS Div Alignment Form

Tags: css, alignment

i tried everything but I am not able to position the two #send and #delete divs on the same level as the form input.

If i try to margin-top the divs, everything follows.

Here the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZZQJx

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;


}

form input {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 30px;

}

form input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

form {
  display: inline;

}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

#send {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;

}

#delete {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;

}

.entry {
  font-family: helvetica;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  -webkit-user-select: none;

}
```

```html
  <h1>ToDo</h1>

    <div class="inline" id="delete"></div>

        <form class="">
            <input style="" type="text" name="input" value="" placeholder=" Einen Eintrag hinzufügen ...">
        </form>

    <div class="inline" id="send"></div>

    <div id="container">

    </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two div's with id's `#delete` / `#send` are set as `display: inline`, you can set them to `vertical-align: top` as follows:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;


}

#delete, #send {
    vertical-align: top;
}

form input {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 30px;

}

form input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

form {
  display: inline;

}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

#send {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;

}

#delete {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;

}

.entry {
  font-family: helvetica;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  -webkit-user-select: none;

}
```

```html
<h1>ToDo</h1>

    <div class="inline" id="delete"></div>

        <form class="">
            <input style="" type="text" name="input" value="" placeholder=" Einen Eintrag hinzufügen ...">
        </form>

    <div class="inline" id="send"></div>

    <div id="container">

    </div>
```